# Angular new router error Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, router

I'm trying to write an app in angularjs by using the new router. But, don't know what's i'm doing wrong. From two days i went through a lot of articles,videos but till now can't able to get a grip on this.

Right now, i'm following this article - http://goo.gl/ayPmxr . My folder setting is like this..

```
- components
-- home
--- home.html

- angular.js
- app.js
- index.html
- router.es5.js
```

My Files -

- index.html


      
          Test new router

  ```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">

      <!-- Multiple viewports require a name -->
      <div ng-viewport="nav"></div>
      <div ng-viewport="main"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="router.es5.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- app.js

[image]

- Chrome Console error

[image]

Can any one please help me to find out where I'm doing wrong & how I can fix that.

Comment: The error is clearly in the 'router.es5.js' file, I recommend you check the versions of angular, and use the [most current version](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/)

Comment: I got this new router file straight from there github account - https://github.com/angular/router/tree/master/dist

Comment: I had the same issue, builded a new version of new router an it worked. In case you need I have builded version in https://github.com/CodeDistillery/router/tree/master/dist

Comment: @vepasto Sorry!!! But, i can't able to get you. Where I'm doing wrong in my code ?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart please try with router.es5.js in our repo

Comment: @vepasto - I'm using your version of 'router.es5.js' file. That console error has been cleared now. But, i can't able to see my home.html content in index.html page. It's just showing as BLANK. Any clue ? My 'home.html' content is "<h3>This is Home Component</h3>".

Comment: In new version of router you must replace  'ng-viewport' to 'ng-outlet' in html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79880/discussion-between-vepasto-and-mi6crazyheart).

Comment: @vepasto Hey, I'm in your chat room.

Comment: @vepasto what did you mean by 'builded a new version'  what did you actually do ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not specifying any component for the `nav` viewport/outlet.

You should either remove from your view

```
<div ng-viewport="nav"></div>
```

or specify a component in your routes, something like

```
components: { 'nav': 'home', 'main': 'home' }
```

It's a known behavior/bug: https://github.com/angular/router/issues/207

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016-01-12, the following works for me:
(just the body of index.html):

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">

  <ng-viewport></ng-viewport>

  <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular-new-router/dist/router.es5.js"></script>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
  <script src="./components/home/home.js"></script>

</body>

// app.js
// This example works as of 2016-01-12 using
// angular 1.5.0-rc.0
// angular-new-router 0.5.3
// Assumes:
// 1. app.js is in the root of the folder structure
// 2. components/home/ folder exists off the root and contains:
//     a.  home.js
//     b.  home.html

angular.module('app', ['ngNewRouter', 'app.home'])
  .controller('AppController', ['$router', AppController]);

function AppController ($router) {
  console.log('made it to AppController');

    $router.config([

        {path: '/', component: 'home' }

    ]);

}
```

I can post home.js and home.html, if needed, but based on the question, the problem is within app.js.

One key difference I spot right away is my (perhaps simplistic) example does NOT enclose the route confiuration inside of a components {} object.

Hope this helps.